# Large Data Array manipulations in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, large-data

I have a large data set in an array <1x43 cell>. The data size is really large, these are some of the cell dimensions - 5 are <1x327680 double>, 11 are <1x1376256 double>

I am attempting to carry out a resample operation which I have a function for. (Function code shown below). I am trying to take an entire cell from the array, perform the Resample operation and store the result back in the same array location or a different one.

However, I get the following error in line 19 or the Resample function -

**"Error using zeros
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
Error in Resample (line 19)
    obj = zeros(t,1);**

I run into an out of memory error when I comment our that line 19.

Please is there a more efficient way to manipulate such large data sets?

Thank you.

**Actual Code:**

```
%% To load each ".dat" file for the 51 attributes to an array.

a = dir('*.dat');

for i = 1:length(a)
eval(['load ' a(i).name ' -ascii']);
end

attributes = length(a);

% Scan folder for number of ".dat" files
datfiles = dir('*.dat'); 

% Count Number of ".dat" files
numfiles = length(datfiles); 

% Read files in to MATLAB
for i = 1:1:numfiles
    A{i} = csvread(datfiles(i).name);
end

% Remove discarded variables
ind = [1 22 23 24 25 26 27 32]; % Variables to be removed.
A(ind) = [];

% Reshape all the data into columns - (n x 1) 
for i = 1:1:length(A)
    temp = A{1,i};
    [x,y] = size(temp);
    if x == 1 && y ~= 1
        temp = temp';
        A{1,i} = temp;
    end
end

% Retrieves the frequency data for the attributes from Excel spreadsheet
frequency = xlsread('C:\Users\aajwgc\Documents\MATLAB\Research Work\Data\testBig\frequency');

% Removing recorded frequency for discarded variables
frequency(ind) = [];

% Upsampling all the attributes to desired frequency
prompt = {'Frequency (Hz):'};
dlg_title = 'Enter desired output frequency for all attributes';
num_lines = 1;
def = {'50'};
answer= inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
OutFreq = str2num(answer{1});

m = 1; 
n = length(frequency);
A_resampled = cell(m,n);
A_resampled(:) = {''};

for i = length(frequency);
    raw = cell2mat(A(1,i));
    temp= Resample(raw, frequency(i,:), OutFreq);
     A_resampled{i} = temp(i);
end
```

**Resample Function:**

```
function obj = Resample(InputData, InFreq, OutFreq, varargin)
%% Preliminary setup
% Allow for selective down-sizing by specifying type
type = 'mean'; %default to the mean/average

if size(varargin,2) > 0
    type = varargin{1};
end

% Determine the necessary resampling factor
factor = OutFreq / InFreq;

%% No refactoring required
if (factor == 1)
    obj = InputData;
%% Up-Sampling required
elseif (factor > 1)
    t = factor * numel(InputData(1:end));
    **obj = zeros(t,1); ----------------> Line 19 where I get the error message.**

    for i = 1:factor:t
        y = ((i-1) / factor) + 1;
        z = InputData(y);
        obj(i:i+factor) = z;
    end
%% Down-Sampling required
elseif (factor < 1)    
    t = numel(InputData(1:end));
    t = floor(t * factor);
    obj = zeros(t,1);
    factor = int32(1/factor);

    if  strcmp(type,'mean') %default is mean (process first)
        for i = 1:t
            y = (factor * (i-1)) + 1;
            obj(i) = mean(InputData(y:y+factor-1));
        end    
    elseif strcmp(type,'min')
        for i = 1:t
            y = (factor * (i-1)) + 1;
            obj(i) = min(InputData(y:y+factor-1));
        end 
    elseif strcmp(type,'max')
        for i = 1:t
            y = (factor * (i-1)) + 1;
            obj(i) = max(InputData(y:y+factor-1));
        end 
    elseif strcmp(type,'mode')
        for i = 1:t
            y = (factor * (i-1)) + 1;
            obj(i) = mode(InputData(y:y+factor-1));
        end 
    elseif strcmp(type,'sum')
        for i = 1:t
            y = (factor * (i-1)) + 1;
            obj(i) = sum(InputData(y:y+factor-1));
        end   
    elseif strcmp(type,'single')
        for i = 1:t
            y = (factor * (i-1)) + 1;
            obj(i) = InputData(y);
        end
    else
        obj = NaN;
    end
else
    obj = NaN;
end
```

Comment: It seems you are passing a cell to resample. So even if value of t equals the largest cell size = <1x1376256 double>, that means 10.5 MB memory. You should not get such an error. What is the value of t in your case when you get the error? Also check memory usage by typing memory in the command line of MATLAB.

Comment: Parag, t evaluates the number of elements that the resampling operation will produce. It didn't run past the first iteration and t was 45875200.

Comment: Then `zeros(t,1)` will result in ~350MB memory. Type `memory` in MATAB command window and see if you have that much memory. Another option is, if you are going to store unsigned 8-bit integers in `obj`, you can write `zeros(t,1,'uint8')`, or `zeros(t,1,'single')`. Whatever suits you.

Comment: I have about 2910MB I wonder why it doesn't work. Also, I tried to avoid using the eval function while reading data by using csvread. But csvread reads file a01 and moves to file a20 instead of a01, a02, a03,... How can I solve this? The data is supplied in ".dat"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the DSP System Toolbox, you could use, e.g., the dsp.FIRInterpolator System Object (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/dsp/ref/dsp.firinterpolatorclass.html ) and call its step() function repeatedly to avoid processing all the data in one go.

By the way, up/downsampling (interpolation and decimation) are more complex concepts than you have assumed; in the most general sense they both require some form of filtering to remove artifacts that such processes generate.

You could design these filters yourself and convolve your signal with them, but doing this filter design requires a solid foundation in signal processing. If you want to go this route, I suggest picking up a textbook from somewhere as easy to get wrong without a reference text.